# cannot import name 'convert_saved_model'

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I am trying to convert a frozen grap to tflite using convert_saved_model in tensorflow, but i am getting the following error

> from tensorflow.contrib.lite.python import convert_saved_model
>
> ImportError: cannot import name 'convert_saved_model'

Here's the code i've been using

```
from tensorflow.contrib.lite.python import convert_saved_model

convert_saved_model.tflite_from_saved_model(saved_model_dir="optimized_graph.pb",
                                         output_file="/tflite_Model")
```

I am using a Windows 8.1 and tensorflow 1.8.
I've tried using toco_convert but got the error

> module tensorflow.contrib has no attribute 'lite'

Comment: Works on v1.8..

Comment: I tried it after installing tensorflow  again, still the same error

Answer (score 0):

Please try with Tensorflow 1.9 and file a Github issue if this is still not working https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues